# Which Duplo bricks have practical uses in System building?

Tags: building, piece-usage, duplo

Traditional 2x4 and 2x2 Duplo bricks can be used to bulk out models and provide a [structural support for landscapes](http://www.flickr.com/photos/billward/110304845/), but have there been any other uses for Duplo bricks of all shapes and sizes in System scale MOC's?

I can find two examples, one of a [Duplo barrel being used for a water tower](http://www.flickr.com/photos/notenoughbricks/3790772324/) and another that uses a [Duplo crown to form the pinnacle of a structure](http://www.flickr.com/photos/bikicsmilan/6882426491/in/contacts/).

Comment: I'm tempted to answer "All of them, depending on your imagination", but that's kind of a lazy answer.

Answer (score 5):

Check out these links:

- [this MOC](http://www.flickr.com/photos/17662487@N07/5262451291) uses a [Duplo Ladybug Base](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=31222#T=C).
- this [modern classic](http://www.flickr.com/photos/bruceywan/6692272517/) uses a Duplo piece as a major element.

Answer (score 2):

I remember reading an article where someone stated that they used the Duplo 2x4 bricks to build up height for large models.  The Duplo was then covered and surrounded by Lego, but that the Duplo added a lot of strength for the weight.

Comment: That's what I was referring to in the first sentence. I'm looking for uses for other Duplo pieces that aren't necessarily bricks.

Comment: Check the youtuber Jangbricks, he is using this filling technique with used Duplo several times in his Lego City when building bigger structures

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I would say that it's only the big, strangely shaped ones that have decent uses.

Obviously you would very rarely use any of the small ones, and system is much better at this. (Only exception I can think of is a piece shortage (heaven forbid!))

I personally have never come across a MOC using DUPLO pieces in large scale, and I doubt you'll find a proper LEGO set using them either.

I would always recommend using system bricks if you can (you probably already know this).

DUPLO bricks do allow you to be lazy though!