# Has any non-Duplo LEGO set included Duplo components?

Tags: duplo

It’s not uncommon for LEGO Technic components to be included in LEGO builds - especially where motion or interaction is needed.

Has the same ever happened with a Duplo component being included in a ‘classic’ LEGO set? Perhaps using their extra size to help build up an area.

(In case clarification is needed, we can define Duplo components as being anything listed under Duplo in the LEGO pick-a-brick service. And any set not branded as Duplo or Technic can be considered a ‘classic’ LEGO set).

Comment: I feel I would be remiss if I did not mention such a near miss as set 30527 <https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=30527-1>

Comment: Thanks for the comment @RSchulz - it's the closest to what I imagined - looking almost like an actual Duplo brick! Shame they didn't actual use Duplo pieces for it.

Comment: Does LEGO Serious Play count here?

Comment: Some of the bad guys in Lego Movie 2 were Duplo but when they made them into sets, they used actual Lego pieces instead. Go figure.

Comment: @MatthewGreen Yeah, but it makes sense when you consider that the target audience for The LEGO Movie 2 is beyond Duplo age, and would much rather have standard LEGO bricks that are inter-compatible with the rest of their collection. With that in mind, those sets achieved a pretty clever compromise if you ask me.

Comment: Not official sets, but: <https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1156/which-duplo-bricks-have-practical-uses-in-system-building?rq=1>

Answer (score 27, accepted):

One instance I can think of is the 52 mm ball, usually used in the DUPLO Ball and Tube system, being present in a couple of "classic" sets. Most notably the Indiana Jones Temple Escape, 7623

[image: 52mm ball]

https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=41250&in=S

[image: Temple Escape set]

It's also present in quite a few Mindstorms and Technic sets, where it is usually used as an object to be grabbed by a gripping mechanism.

Answer (score 11):

There was almost (probably) a Technic BIONICLE set with a [Duplo tread piece](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=71981).

[image: Duplo tread]

That set would have been the Sand Tarakava ([low-res](https://www.maskofdestiny.com/news/%C2%85-the-answer), [high-res](https://www.maskofdestiny.com/news/icfta-sand-tarakava), [other](https://www.maskofdestiny.com/news/icfta-sand-tarakava-addendum)), a smaller set that was meant to compliment the [8549 Tarakava set](https://brickset.com/sets/8549-1/Tarakava).

[image: Sand Tarakava]

This prototype set was given to Saffire to develop [the cancelled 2001 PC video game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Bionicle:_The_Legend_of_Mata_Nui), and later changed hands.

Ultimately this set was not produced, so it's possible it would have undergone additional revisions if it had been. Changing the tread seems like it would have been a rather drastic change though, especially compared to the minor changes seen in other prototype models Saffire worked with.